# Passing Data from form with Ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax, database, forms

Wondering if someone could help me. I have next to no knowledge with Ajax, and after many attempts at trying to pass my User1_id and Text through to my insert.php I've had no luck with inserting the data I want to my database.

As my profile.php and insert.php stands, the form submits to the database, but when the user submits the form it navigates to the insert.php and would rather have the Ajax send the data and stay on the Profile.php at all times, I feel this is a much better approach when creating such functions.

I'm wondering if someone can guide me in the right direction on how I'd go about doing this.

Profile.php Form

```
<form id="FormId" action="" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" value="<? echo $user1_id ?>">
        <textarea placeholder="Whats New??" id="FormId" name="status"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
```

Insert.php

```
    <?
    session_start();
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
    include "db_connect.php";
    if (isset($_GET['status']))  {
         $status = $_GET['status'];
    }
    $user1_id=$_SESSION['id'];



if ($_GET['status']) {
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO feed (status,user1_id) VALUES ('$status', '$user1_id')")  or die (mysql_error());
if($query){
    echo "Posted Into Database";
}

exit();
}
?>
```

I know I need something similiar to this.. But I think I'm stuck more on the var/data part.

```
$("form#myFormId").submit(function() {
    var mydata = $("form#myFormId").serialize();
    alert(mydata); // it's only for test
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "insert.php",
        data: mydata,
        success: function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

But don't know how to go about it.

Any guidence is appreciated. Not asking anyone to write the code out for me. But good direction is welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like to say thank you to both of you for your time and help. I re-wrote the code and have now got it working.

Here is the final code
PROFILE.PHP/JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function createstatus(content){
$.post("insert.php", { user1_id: content } );
refreshstream();
}

function createwallpost(content,user1_id){

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "insert.php",
   data: "status="+content+"&user1_id="+user1_id,
   success: function(){
     document.location = document.location;
   }
 });

}
</script>

    <form action="insert.php" method="POST" target="ifr1" class="form_statusinput">
        <input type="hidden" name="user1_id" value="<?php echo $user1_id ?>">
        <input type="text" name="status" id="status" class="homescreen_status_input" placeholder="Say something">
        <iframe name="ifr1" id="ifr1" style="display:none;"></iframe>
    </form>
```

INSERT.PHP

```
<?
session_start();
include "db_connect.php";
if (isset($_POST['status']))  {
     $status = $_POST['status'];
}

$user1_id = $_POST['user1_id'];


if ($_POST['status']) {
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO feed (status,user1_id) VALUES ('$status', '$user1_id')")  or die (mysql_error());
if($query){
    echo "Posted Into Database";
}

exit();
} 


?>
```

I decided to go with post instead of the GET method, as I feel its securer and passes more information through smoothly.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Change your ajax part to:

```
$("form#myFormId").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();  //prevent default submit
  ........
```

Your hidden input should have name

```
<input name="userId" type="hidden" value="<? echo $user1_id ?>">
```

And in php,

```
$userId = $_GET["userId"];
```

Change id of textarea, its same to your formid and ids need to be unique,
so change your textarea id, and You can try passing data as:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "insert.php",
        data:"status="+$("#yourTextareaId").val()+"&userId="+$("#yourHiddenInputId").val(),
        ......
```

Comment: I changed as suggested. When I submit, its telling me in firefox.."This user does not exist" then logging me out, making it seem that its not passing the user1_id through to the insert.php page..That is what I'm looking for.

Comment: add name to your hidden input field for which you have added userId as value, and get it from PHP side

Comment: Still throws the same error. The ajax isn't passing the id of the user so do I have to change the DATA field to pass it?

Comment: you cannot have same ids, you are using same id for your form and textarea field, so change id of your textarea... and you are getting user_id from session, so it'not the problem with ajax code

Comment: This is my output, but it still keeps outputting the same error of this user does not exist. Must be something else. 
Mysite.com/profile.php?user1_id=6&status=dddd&Submit=Submit

Comment: Well I echo the $_SESSION out in my page and it shows as 6, it also shows this when I submit the form with everything you'e suggested I update. So I'm either missing/inputted something wrong..Or its something else. 
Like I said..I have next to no knowledge. I do however understand what you're saying/writing up..So have maybe some knowledge.

Comment: It seems its not navigating away from profile.php!

Think it has something to do with this bit of Ajax

var mydata = $("#formid").serialize();
    alert(mydata); // it's only for test

Comment: @dave you can check the headers using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox.

Comment: Cool. I have that installed. So I'll give it a blast. :D Thanks Travis

Comment: Firebug is passing out this error.

$ is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

$(document).ready(function (e) {